# SystemTray not supported on Windows 10

Tags: java, system-tray

With Java 8 sdk, when I do

```
if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
   logger.error("SystemTray IS supported");
} else {
    logger.error("SystemTray IS NOT supported");
}
```

Why SystemTray is not supported on Windows 10 ?

And what can I do to make it supported ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can set headless property from code too:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem!
My JVM was just starting in HeadLess mode!

I do not understand why... maybe because I do not have any GUI excepted this icon.

TO deactivate Headless mode, start the program with `-Djava.awt.headless=false`